# Install python3 in ubuntu 16.04 docker image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am trying to install python 3.6 in ubuntu 16.04 docker image. It was working fine before. But today it is started showing this error.

```
Step 8/14 : RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
 ---> Running in a27c7c55afef
 This PPA has been removed from public access as part of a protest against the abuse of open-source projects by large companies. For more detail visit the main page here: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf

If you are a company and you would like this PPA to continue then let me know your preferred route for contributions and I will arrange something.
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am not sure about this. I didn't understand the problem. How I can solve this issue.

My docker code below:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY requirements.txt /


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common vim
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip python3.6-venv python-dev libssl-dev swig
RUN apt-get install -y git

# update pip
RUN python3.6 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3.6 -m pip install wheel

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting seems pretty obvious:

> This PPA has been removed from public access as part of a protest against the abuse of open-source projects by large companies. For more detail visit the main page here: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf

The author has removed the PPA you're trying to use. You will need to find another PPA, or install Python yourself from source, or use a different base image. For example, you could use the standard `python:3.6` base image if you need Python 3.6 (or just `python:3.7` or `python:3.8`, depending on your needs).

Comment: Thanks @larsks for quick problem explanation. Can you suggest how can I get valid Python PPAs. I found one which is "ppa:deadsnakes/ppa". But I have doubt on their disclaimer. 
there's no guarantee of timely updates in case of security problems or other issues. If you want to use them in a security-or-otherwise-critical environment (say, on a production server), you do so at your own risk.

Comment: I am unable to provide any information about available PPAs. I would typically just use a more recent version of Ubuntu which includes the necessary version of Python natively.